# Copy folder structure and content of specific folders

Tags: powershell, xcopy

So I've found xcopy super helpful to copy entire folder structures. But I also need to copy the contents of specific folders into the new directories as well.

For example:

```
1. C:\OriginalDir
- \This
     * \Test
- \That
     * \Test
- \Other
```

I can use: `xcopy C:\OriginalDir C:\TempDir /e /t` to copy the entire structure of the `C:\OriginalDir`. However, I also need to copy the contents of both `\Test` folders into the new directory as well. I'm fairly new to xcopy and I've also looked into robocopy. Is there a way to do this? I'm trying to accomplish this in powershell and thought about iterating through the folder structure, but that still doesn't store the parent folder structure when I finally reach the Test folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Steve for getting me started and getting me thinking about this correctly. Ended up scripting it out manually without using RoboCopy or Xcopy as I could not get them to work exactly how I wanted to.

```
$target = "C:\\TestTemp"
foreach($item in (Get-ChildItem "C:\\OriginalDir\\This" -Recurse)){

    if ($item.PSIsContainer -and ($item.Name -eq "obj" -or $item.Name -eq "bin")){
        $tempPath = $target
        $path = $item.FullName
        $trimmed = $path.TrimStart("C:\\OriginalDir")
        $pieces = $trimmed.Split("\\");

        foreach($piece in $pieces){

            $tempPath = "$tempPath\$piece"
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$tempPath"
            if($piece -eq "Test" -or $piece -eq "Temp"){
            Copy-Item -path $path\** -Destination $tempPath -Recurse -force
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried robocopy - for example:

```
$source = "C:\Your\Source\Directory"
$dest = "C:\Your\Destination\Directory"
robocopy $source $dest /e
```

The 'e' switch will copy subdirectories and their contents (including empty subdirectories).

If you wanted to exclude the \Other directory (it's not entirely clear from your question), you could do the following:

```
  robocopy $source $dest /e /xf *
```

(This just copies the directory structure with no files copied)

```
robocopy $source $dest /XD C:\Other /e
```

(This copies files, but excludes the named directories)

You can find more information here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc733145.aspx

Edit:

In order to only copy directories beginning with 'Test', you could do the following:

```
  $exclude = gci C:\OriginalDir -ad | ?{ $_.Name -notlike 'Test*'
  robocopy $source $dest /XD $exclude /e
```

If your folder structure is more than one level deept, you could use the -recurse switch on Get-Childitem

Comment: So for instance lets assume I have 15 folders. I need to copy all directories labeled "test" and their contents. I need to be able to copy just those specific contents to the new location with the correct directory structure without any of the other contents outside of them. The exclude option is nice, but not what I need as I would have to exclude a ton of directories and the directories will change over time so I can't just hard code them either.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include only the directories labelled 'test'.